# Count number of occurrences in a column?

Tags: sql

I have a table column where the same value can be repeated in across the several rows or maybe not. I want to return a count of all the values. A structure of my table is shown below

```
id | name | code 
1  | xyz  | 1.1
2  | 123  | 1.1
3  | foo  | 2.1
3  | bob  | 3.1
4  | roy  | 2.1
```

I want to count the values in `code` and so in this case the result should be 3

Comment: And where does the "3" come from?

Comment: This is a very unclear question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 3 distinct values in the code column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to count unique values of `code`, as I understand the question. If so, SQL has `count(distinct)`.

```
select count(distinct code)
from t;
```

Comment: thanks.... what about if I want to return all the fields. will accept answer in 5 minutes

Comment: @net: please do not extend the scope of your question once you get an answer